# Change column layout with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout as follows for mobile ..

```
    +------------------------+
    | (col-md-6)   Div 1     |
    +------------------------+
    | (col-md-6)   Div 2     |
    +------------------------+
    | (col-md-6)   Div 3     |
    +------------------------+
    | (col-md-6)   Div 4     |
    +------------------------+
    | (col-md-6)   Div 5     |
    +------------------------+
    | (col-md-6)   Div 6     |
    +------------------------+
    | (col-md-6)   Div 7     |
    +------------------------+
```

When the screen widens or goes on tablet the layout changes as expected to ...

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 1     | (col-md-6)   Div 2     |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 3     | (col-md-6)   Div 4     |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 5     | (col-md-6)   Div 6     |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 7     |
+------------------------+
```

But I would like the layout to look like ..

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 1     | (col-md-6)   Div 5     |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 2     | (col-md-6)   Div 6     |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 3     | (col-md-6)   Div 7     |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| (col-md-6)   Div 4     |
+------------------------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. I posted an answer for you. Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easyest way to achieve this is to duplicate the content into 2 blocks. First block will be visible on extra small, small and medium devices (1 div/line) and the other block will be visible on large devices (2 div/line).

- Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/4v4Tu/embedded/result/)
- Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/4v4Tu/)

---

```
<section class="hidden-lg">
    <div class="col-md-12">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Div 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Div 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Div 4</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Div 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Div 6</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Div 7</div>
</section>

<section class="visible-lg">
    <div class="col-lg-6">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Div 5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Div 2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Div 6</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Div 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Div 7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Div 4</div>
</section>
```

*It's not an optimized solution, but it is very helpful in many situations. I use this solution alot along with bootstrap.*

Answer (score 0):

what I have worked is replacing the divs by `.replaceWith()` at a particular window width (700px for my example, set it as according to bootstrap media queries as below).

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```

[Result here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/yyPrg/53/embedded/result/) for wide screens.

due to lack of time, I have not added `.resize()` function; so you need to refresh the screen to see the effect each time, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/yyPrg/53/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 0ne">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 two">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 three">3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 four">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 five">5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 six">6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 seven">7</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 eight">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.col-sm-6 {
    background:grey;
}
```

jquery // Please shorten code if you can, I used basic jQuery as I am new to it.

```
one = $('.one');
two = $('.two');
three = $('.three');
four = $('.four');
five = $('.five');
six = $('.six');
seven = $('.seven');
eight = $('.eight');

tone = one.clone();
ttwo = two.clone();
tthree = three.clone();
tfour = four.clone();
tfive = five.clone();
tsix = six.clone();
tseven = seven.clone();
teight = eight.clone();



if ($(window).width() > 700) {
    two.replaceWith(tfive);
    three.replaceWith(ttwo);
    four.replaceWith(tsix);
    five.replaceWith(tthree);
    six.replaceWith(tseven);
    seven.replaceWith(tfour);
}
```